# Implied Distributions from forward prices

Tags: option-pricing, forward, distribution

I understand that the common way to arrive at an implied distribution for an underlying is through the price of its call options as per the Breeden-Litzenberger formula.

I am wondering if its possible to do it via looking at forwards or is it a lost cause since forwards are really just a function of the discount rate and dividend rate rather than an "implied" price?

Comment: Might be better to add in a longer title

Answer (score 2):

You are right: the forward has no information about the future (market inferred) price distribution. In fact, under the risk-free measure, it is just the undiscounted expectation of the price, taking into account possible dividends, repo, borrowing costs, storage, etc (i.e. anything that could make the future contract more/less appealing than just buying the spot).

Therefore, to get some information about the density, you need some other financial contract that has some non-linearity and that depend on (and allow you to extract) this information. As you can see from Breeden-Litzenberger, the more options you have, the more resolution you can obtain for the distribution.